# Sorting array of n objects - uasort and sort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i get data from a database which results in array with unlimited objects which look like this (example given with 2 objects, but there can be more):

```
array(2) 
{
  [0]              object(stdClass)#34 (6) 
  {
    ["id"]         string(2) "32"
    ["voting_id"]  string(2) "42"
    ["answer"]     string(4) "No"
    ["color"]      string(7) "#F7464A"
    ["votes"]      string(1) "1"
    ["percentage"] float(0.166666666667)
  }
  [1]              object(stdClass)#33 (6) 
  {
    ["id"]         string(2) "31"
    ["voting_id"]  string(2) "42"
    ["answer"]     string(2) "Yes"
    ["color"]      string(7) "#E2EAE9"
    ["votes"]      string(1) "5"
    ["percentage"] float(0.833333333333)
  }
}
```

I want to sort this array either by votes or by percentage asc/desc. I tried it with:

```
function sorterVotes($a, $b) {
    if ( $a->votes < $b->votes ) return -1;
    if ( $a->votes > $b->votes ) return 1;
    return 0;
}

usort($answers, 'sorterVotes');
var_dump($answers);
```

But the only thing that gets sorted is that the [0] and the [1] changes, but this is not helpful for me because i go through that array via foreach later.
How can i sort this array of n objects by votes / percentage and asc/desc?

Would be great if anybody can help. Thanks.

Comment: Why not sort in DBMS via `ORDER BY`?

Comment: you probably find it more flexible to use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/array_multisort) but then you need to index the sort-values (e.g. votes / percentage) first.

Comment: Alma, because votes and percentages will be added to the object afterwards...